# How to copy a file into a directory with the rsync or something else?

Tags: c

In this code, I am trying to copy the `file.txt` to the directory named `folder` but when I run the code, it gives me the following error. I searched online but didn't find a solution.

**Error**

```
rsync: change_dir "/home/runner/TestC1/text" failed: Not a directory (20)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

**Code**

```
char *transfer(char *f1, char *f2){
    char cmd[500];
    snprintf(cmd, 500, "rsync -a %s/ %s", f1, f2);
    system(cmd);    
    return 0;
}

int main(){
  transfer("/home/runner/TestC1/file.txt", "/home/runner/TestC1/folder");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about `PATH_MAX` instead of arbitrary, probably wrong values like `500`. If you're' taking two path arguments you'll need *at least* `PATH_MAX * 2` plus whatever you need for the command itself. You'll also need to account for the fact that command line arguments **need escaping** as any filenames with spaces or irregular characters in them will cause this to fail. It also opens you up to **shell injection attacks** which is extremely bad if this is public facing code.

Comment: `rsync -a %s %s"` your file does not have an `'/'` at the end. The `'/'` at the end of the *source* with rsync tells rsync to copy the *contents* of the *directory* and not the directory itself. You are copying a single file. The `'/'` doesn't belong.

Comment: There are [`exec` functions](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) that take argument lists and avoid a lot of this mess. I'd strongly recommend using those instead of a vulnerable, difficult to use `system` call.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, David! It worked.

Comment: Good deal. But take the advise @tadman gave and look at `execv`, etc.. and `fork()` for spawning external processes. `system` is rather limited. (but for your purpose here, it does okay)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Okay, I will look at it. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This problem got solved but when I transfer a `file` from a `directory1/file` to `directory2` then the `file` moves to `directory2`. But I want to copy the `file` and keep the copy of this `file` in `directory1` also.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. `rsync` simply copies the file preserving all file-times and permissions when the `-a` option is given. It isn't deleting the original.

Comment: You can (and should) test your rsync options from the command line first. When you have rsync doing exactly what you want, you just need to make sure your code produces the same command as the one you already tested. If you problem is with rsync itself, that's not a programming question.